Cannot run "sudo apt upgrade" when trying to upgrade python3-colcon-notification package
I am trying to upadte my packages because when trying to use catkin_make install I get the error
`error: option --install-layout not recognized
CMake Error at tada_ros/catkin_generated/safe_execute_install.cmake:4 (message):
  
  execute_process(/home/pi/catkin_ws_tadaros/build/tada_ros/catkin_generated/python_distutils_install.sh)
  returned error code
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  tada_ros/cmake_install.cmake:41 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:134 (include)


make: *** [Makefile:74: install] Error 1
Invoking "make install -j4 -l4" failed

`
I suspect this is because the package cannot mentioned in the title cannot be upgraded. This is error message I get when trying to upgrade it
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdav1d3 python-colorzero python3-rosdistro
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-colcon-notification
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/11.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-colcon-notification_0.2.15-1_all.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/DebianFiles.py", line 124, in readdeb
    output = subprocess.check_output(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['dpkg-deb', '-f', '/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-colcon-notification_0.2.15-1_all.deb', 'Package', 'Source', 'Version', 'Architecture', 'Status']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 281, in <module>
    main(config)
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 96, in main
    pkg = DebianFiles.Package(deb)
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/DebianFiles.py", line 215, in __init__
    parser.readdeb(self.path)
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/DebianFiles.py", line 128, in readdeb
    {'what': file, 'errmsg': str(ex)}) from ex
NameError: name 'file' is not defined

dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-colcon-notification_0.2.15-1_all.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-colcon-notification_0.2.15-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-colcon-notification_0.2.15-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


